# combinatorial maths recurrence relations for distribution of N objects into 3 different boxes

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

Given N balls which are red, green or blue in color.And three boxes R,B,G.In how many ways these N balls can be distributed so that box R contains atleast r no of red balls, B contains atleast b no of blue balls , and G contains atleast g no of balls.
Note balls of same color are indistinguishable.

What I am trying to build is a recurrence relation.But problem is that the boxes may contain more than the balls atleast required also ...Nd this is where i am not able to move forward..
please help to me find a recurrence relation `f(r,b,g,N)=??`
for base cases it should be following two condition

`r+b+g<=N and max(r,g,b)<=N`

Comment: Perhaps you could give this a more descriptive title to make the question easier to find later.

Comment: @Travis is it ok now ..?

Comment: Yes, it's much clearer now, and it will probably get your question more attention besides.

Comment: Did you by any chance mean that the $r$ balls are red, the $b$ balls are blue and the $g$ balls are green?

Comment: @barakmanos yeah

Comment: Shouldn't we pretend to know how many of the balls are red, how many are blue, and how many are green?

Comment: @DanielV  no such constraints are given ...just the total no of balls are N

Comment: There is no definite answer here, unless you tell us how many balls of each color (for example, $\frac{1}{3}N$).

Comment: @barakmanos can't we assume that from given N ,r,g,b ..in how many ways we can have N>=r+g+b ?? and also that max(r,b,g)<=N

Comment: @barakmanos or in different words you say in how many ways you can make a string of length N consisting of only R,G,B letters such that there are atleast g no of G , r no of R and b no of B.

Comment: The number of ways depends on the colour distribution of the "extra" $N-r-g-b$ balls.

Comment: @AndréNicolas and how can we get a recurrence relation for `N-r-g-b` balls .?

Comment: I thinhk people are trying to tell you that there isn't enough information to get a recurrence.